# Connection Refused When Connecting to Elasticsearch Remotely

Tags: python, elasticsearch, connection

I'm trying to use elasticsearch-py to connect to my server, but I'm having some serious issues. For whatever reason, when I pass in the credentials through python my connection is being refused.

Initially, I thought it could be a result of nginx configurations or bad certificates, but updating these did not improve the situation. I can log into the server from the browser, curl, or my phone using RFC-1738 formatted URLs (http://user:pass@111.222.333.444/space)

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/elasticsearch.yml` put

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

to allow access from remote system. OR, replace `0.0.0.0` with the IP of the network/sub-network you would be using for accessing the Elastic Search.

Comment: Thanks- any thoughts on why it wouldn't be able to find my indices any more?

Comment: @SeanVDH: Indices are not restricted from where you are accessing them. Verify that you are using the correct URL. After making the above changes, if you are able to see the indices on the local machine (machine on which ElasticSearch is running), you should be able to see it on the remote machine as well

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My nginx proxy rules must be malformed. Thanks for the help